# read contents from $(this) selector and its children separately?

Tags: jquery

how to read contents from $(this) selector and its children separately?

```
    <div class="para">
      <h1 class="hd">heading 1</h1>
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nunc tincidunt pharetra         est, quis facilisis purus elementum ut. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos.
    </div>
```

I can read the contents of the `<h1>`separately using $(this).children("h1").text() but how do you read the content from the  excluding `<h1>`?

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get the content via a [`.clone()`](http://api.jquery.com/clone/), like this:

```
$(this).clone().children("h1").remove().end().text()
```

[You can give it a try here](http://jsfiddle.net/nick_craver/Ln6hP/), all we're doing is cloning the element, removing that `<h1>` from the clone then getting the text out.

Comment: Is this answer any better then my suggestion? I am not that great at javascript and curious why you chose this approach ?

Comment: @Chris - There are a few issues with your version, I'll comment on your answer.

Comment: alas, it just seems you should be able to do that without the clone :(

Comment: @Mark - You could do something like `$(this).contents()[2].nodeValue` but it's a bit more brittle, or a loop through text nodes to find a non-empty one, not sure what's most optimal here, depends on the programmer I suppose?

Comment: @Nick yes, kind of what I was considering but still did not give me that "clean" feeling :) - I have often seen questions about getting the text "not" within a child element of an element so it seems to bring to pause a lot of users.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(this).find(:not(h1)).text();
```

Where you take this and then find anything in it which is not an h1.

Edit: Sorry, val() was incorrect needed to be text per comment, thanks.

Comment: This finds all descendant elements that aren't `<h1>`, but you need quotes, so `":not(h1)"` since `.find()` takes a string.  But, jQuery doesn't select text elements like this, so you'd still get am empty string every time :)